# How change rules for Gson parser?

Tags: android, gson

I want to change rules for Gson parser (json parser wrote by google for Android). For example I have the object of class:

```
enum Type
{
    PRIMARY,
    SECONDARY
}

class A
{
    public int i = 4;
    public Type type = Type.PRIMARY;
}

A a = new A();
```

Now if I will convert that object via Gson converter:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement json = gson.toJson(a);
```

I will get that json element: {"i":4,"type":"PRIMARY"}. Instead of this I want to get: {"i":4,"type":0}, i.e. ordinal of type instead of a name of it.

How can I do that?

Tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer:

For doing that need to create Gson object from GsonBuilder. But before that register a new type hierarchy adapter for gson builder for Enum.class type with your own json serializer that will do the work.

```
// new Json serializer for Enum<?> class
class ObjectTypeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Enum<?>>
{
    private static final JsonParser mParser = new JsonParser();

    public JsonElement serialize(Enum<?> object_,
        Type type_,
        JsonSerializationContext context_)
    {
        // that will convert enum object to its ordinal value and convert it to json element
        return mParser.parse(((Integer)object_.ordinal()).toString());  
    }
}

// creation of gson builder 
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

// registration of type hierarchy adapter
gsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Enum.class, new ObjectTypeSerializer());   

// creation gson from builder
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Now gson will do the work!